# android - OpenGLRenderer﹕ Wrong thread! crash coming from Android Hardware Acceleration UI Library

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am consistently getting this crash while randomly browsing my app on the Nexus 7, 9 and 10 running Android 5.1.1. Not exactly sure what's causing it since it's not happening on any other Android device.

```
27432-27447/? A/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Wrong thread!
```

WebView crash handler dump

```
29120-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
29120-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ O A arm 04 armv7l 3.4.0-gfe3bd61 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 27 22:29:37 UTC 2015
```

..........

```
29120-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
27432-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
27432-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ Chrome build fingerprint:
27432-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ 2.1
27432-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ 33
27432-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ 92675e2e-3e24-4fdd-9bc9-d979deace950
27432-27447/? W/google-breakpad﹕ ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
27432-27447/? E/chromium﹕ ### WebView Version 43.0.2357.121 (code 2357121
```

Actual Crash here....

```
27432-27447/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 27447 (FinalizerDaemon)
550-614/? E/WifiStateMachine﹕ WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=34.96 rxSuccessRate=82.63 targetRoamBSSID=any RSSI=-44
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
82-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'google/razor/flo:5.1.1/LMY48G/1965118:user/release-keys'
82-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'arm'
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 27432, tid: 27447, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.myapp <<<
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ Abort message: 'Wrong thread!'
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00006b37  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 b3d28db8  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 ffffffff  r9 b4a35000  sl 13171f40  fp 1334e3e0
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 00006b37  sp b3d28580  lr b6dd73c5  pc b6dfa82c  cpsr 600f0010

182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 0003a82c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 000173c1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 00017fd3  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 00014795  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 00012f44  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 00007b51  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+88)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06 pc 00035bd3  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07 pc 00035be9  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08 pc 00023e85  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09 pc 00023f0d  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10 pc 00024023  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11 pc 000241ff  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #12 pc 0002499f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #13 pc 00032f61  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #14 pc 00032f8b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #15 pc 00032f8b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #16 pc 00032f21  /system/lib/libhwui.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #17 pc 00034e03  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::~RenderNode()+14)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #18 pc 00034e85  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::~RenderNode()+4)
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #19 pc 0007cdd7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
182-182/? I/DEBUG﹕ #20 pc 00017c0d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

I think that libhwui.so is Android's Hardware Acceleration UI Library so it seems like that's where the crash is coming from. Anyone have any idea what causes this kind of crash and how one can try to debug this issue?